# MAUI How to bind Shell BackgroundColor by boolean variable to StaticResource color?

Tags: converters, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I will bind StaticResource colors as BackgroundColor to the Shell (at AppShell.xaml) by a boolean variable.
My solution does not work. I get always the default BackgroundColor (see Style on the bottom). I get never the *Yellow100* or *Gray500*.
**Where ist the mistake?**

```
<Shell ...  
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels"
    x:DataType="viewModels:AppShellViewModel"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding IsOnline, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" >

    <Shell.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:IsStringNotNullOrEmptyConverter x:Key="IsStringNotNullOrEmptyConverter" />
            <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" TrueObject="{StaticResource Yellow100}" FalseObject="{StaticResource Gray500}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Shell.Resources>
```

I tried also using *x:TypeArguments="Color"* or *x:DataType="Color"*

My ViewModel:

```
public partial class AppShellViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isOnline;

    public AppShellViewModel(ConnectionStateService connectionStateService)
    {
        IsOnline = connectionStateService.IsOnline();
    }
}
```

My Colors.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">

    <Color x:Key="Gray500">#6E6E6E</Color>
    <Color x:Key="Yellow100">#F7B548</Color>
```

**I tried this and this works fine:**

```
BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Yellow100Accent}"
```

A default color ist set via Style at Styles.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="Shell" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor"
            Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Primary}, Dark={StaticResource Gray950}}" /> ...
```

AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class AppShell
{
    private readonly AppShellViewModel _appShellViewModel;

    public AppShell(AppShellViewModel appShellAppShellViewModel)
    {
        _appShellViewModel = appShellAppShellViewModel;

        BindingContext = _appShellViewModel;

        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(FirstPage), typeof(FirstPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(
    ...
    } ....
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Where and when does `IsOnline` get updated? Have you defined the background color somewhere else already? Setting it in other pages using `Shell.BackgroundColor="DarkGreen"` will overwrite whatever you define in your AppShell.xaml.

Comment: Please show your AppShell.xaml.cs

Comment: @Julian I updated the initial article with information about default color. IsOnline is set at the ViewModel (see article). The background color is not overwrite outside of AppShell.

Comment: You probably forgot to set the `BindingContext`.

Comment: @Julian How to use the BindingContext? I tried: <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" BindingContext="BackgroundColor".. /> It's not working.

Comment: @Julian I don't want to display the complete AppShell.xaml.cs publicly. This is extensive and contains code that is not my property. But I can answer specific questions about it.

Comment: You can show a simplified version or a reproduction that doesn't contain any of your business critical code. That's the purpose of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). How do you instantiate your `AppShellViewModel`? Please show a simplified version of the AppShell.xaml.cs (strip out everything that is irrelevant to the problem).

Comment: @Julian I added the AppShell.xaml.cs to the initial article.

Comment: The `BindingContext` is set, so that's okay. However, usually, this is done *after* calling `InitializeComponent()`. Try switching the order, so that `InitializeComponent()` is the first thing in the AppShell contructor.

Comment: @Julian After changing the order the TopBar is white (not default color, not binded color). On all my pages I got first the BindingContext to the ViewModel and than the InitializeComponent();.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datatrigger may be a better choice:

```
<Shell.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger TargetType="Shell" Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Yellow100Accent}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger  TargetType="Shell" Binding="{Binding IsOnline}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Blue100Accent}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Shell.Triggers>
```